# JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: How to find the difference between two lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract data from the text file written by a location tracking app. Some lines parse perfectly, but then everything comes to a halt with the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 317 (char 316)`

I tracked down the offending line in the file. That line and the line before (which parses fine) are:

```
2020-01-11 05:18:03.000000 {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-6.242419339685425,53.424301141597915]},"properties":{"motion":[],"speed":-1,"battery_level":0.4000000059604645,"altitude":65,"battery_state":"unplugged","horizontal_accuracy":65,"vertical_accuracy":10,"timestamp":"2020-01-11T05:18:03Z","wifi":""}}
2020-01-11 05:18:17.000000 {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-6.242454479088605,53.424276709505094]},"properties":{"motion":["stationary"],"speed":-1,"battery_level":0.4000000059604645,"altitude":65,"battery_state":"unplugged","horizontal_accuracy":65,"vertical_accuracy":10,"timestamp":"2020-01-11T05:18:17Z","wifi":"Dublin Airport Free WiFi"}}
```

The code I am using is:

```
with open(InputFile, 'r') as f:
    myresponse = f.readlines() # a list of strings

for item in myresponse:
    dataparts = [] 
    dataparts = item.split(' ') # a list of three elements
    geodata = json.loads(dataparts[2]) # Convert it to a dictionary of 3 elements, strings
```

The error occurs in other files too, and is always at roughly the same point in the line, around the information for WiFi. I have examined the lines as much as possible, looking for invisibles, etc etc and cannot see anything wrong with them.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `dataparts = item.split(' ')` but the string "Dublin Airport Free WiFi" has spaces. Use the `maxsplit` parameter: `dataparts = item.split(' ', 2)`

Comment: Or, if the timestamps are always the same length: `geodata = json.loads(item[27:])`

Comment: Thank you very much. I had been ignorant of `maxsplit`. The timestamps are the same length, and I suppose I could use `item.find('{')` to get the position to start the slice. I can guarantee that the third item after the split is the one I want, so that is what I will use.